# Redirect page Python to Home page using HTML

Tags: python

I am new to python.

I have a login page using html and a create account page using python.
When I press submit on html form in login page i redirect to create account page. I need to redirect to home page from create account page.

I don`t know how to do that.

I have seen many questions like this here but it doesn`t work for me.

Thank you

This is my create account page:

```
#!/Python27/python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-


# Import modules for CGI handling
import MySQLdb
import cgi, cgitb

# Open database connection
db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost", "root", "", "moviedb" )

# prepare a cursor object using cursor() method
cursor = db.cursor()

# Create instance of FieldStorage 
form = cgi.FieldStorage() 

# Get data from fields
email = form.getvalue('email')
nume  = form.getvalue('nume')
password = form.getvalue('password')

# execute SQL query using execute() method.
try:
    cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO user(name,
         email, password)
         VALUES (%s,%s,%s)""",(nume,email,password))
    # Commit your changes in the database
    db.commit()
except:
    db.rollback()

# disconnect from server
db.close()

print "Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8"
print
```

Comment: This is completely unanswerable without knowing anything about your "python" account page. Are you using a framework? Which? What does the code look like?

Comment: I am not using any framework. My create account page looks empty. it has  code only for inserting users to database, this works. I thought maybe i can add some lines to redirect to another page. I didn`t think that the code is relevant. Thank you

Comment: How could the code not be relevant? It is the code that will redirect you back to the home page after inserting it into the database. How are you making this into a web page, if you're not using a framework?

Comment: I have changed the post with create account page code.

Comment: Please look at something like Flask to create Web Apps in python. There is a redirect function there

Comment: thank you @cricket_007 i will take a look

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered creating a .htaccess file for redirections?

Comment: well, i need to make this using python, this is my homework from school. thank you anyway

Comment: @cricket_007 although this is not a very good answer, it does have nothing at all to do with PHP.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comments, it is the job of the code in the account page to redirect back where you want after processing. At the moment, all you are doing is displaying an empty page. Instead, you should tell the browser where to go.

So, replace your `print "content-type..."` statement with the following:

```
print "Location: /"
print
```

Comment: Well, change `/` to whatever the address of your home page is, then.